# Lines printed by a child process to stdout

Tags: c, process, operating-system, child-process

How can I know the number of lines printed by a child process in C.
Better explanation of the scenario,
I have a c program in which I am going to fork a process. So I want to know the number of lines printed by the child process to the stdout.

Comment: @MarcB but how to achieve the same in C??

Comment: capture the child's stdout in the parent, or wrap printf() and add a counter?

Comment: Perhaps program the child program to count the number of lines it prints and communicate that number back to the parent via an IPC mechanism?

Comment: @MarcB capture child's Stdout? How can I do that . could you be more speific?

Comment: @MultimediaMike i am trying to create a small sandbox like a program as a project. So the parent program (i.e the sandbox) has to find the behaviour of child process on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can override stdin, if ss is a file containing 12:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("%p\n", stdin);
    FILE * fd = fopen("ss", "r+");
    printf("%p\n", fd);
    stdin = fd;
    printf("%p\n", stdin);
    int a = 0;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
➜ ./a
0x7fff70ab9350
0x7fff70abf280
0x7fff70abf280
12
```

Answer (score 0):

> capture child's Stdout? How can I do that . could you be more speific?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    FILE *fp = popen("ls -1", "r");
    int c, l = 0;
    do if (c = fgetc(fp), c == '\n') ++l; while (c != EOF);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("The child process printed %d lines.\n", l);
}
```